# Criação de dois projetos em único repositório Git

Tags: git

Estou criando um projeto em Java web e quero criar um outro projeto em Android.
Mas gostaria de criar apenas um repositório e dentro do mesmo possuir estes dois projetos com suas respectivas árvores de *commits*, como se fossem componentes separados.

É possível criar algo assim no Git?

Comment: você pode separar os projetos em pastas... mas não sei se é a maneira correta

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Não é possível. O Git tem suas vantagens, mas uma das desvantagens é justamente essa. O Git trabalha com o repositório como um todo. Na verdade, é mais comum quando precisa de melhor organização e controle de acesso ter uma separação de projetos em partes e cada uma ter seu próprio repositório.

É evidente que pode, ainda que não recomendado, colocar ambos no mesmo repositório, mas será uma coisa só do ponto de vista do Git. Dá para fazer, mas qualquer tentativa de administrar como se fossem coisas separadas vai trazer mais confusão.

Separe em dois repositórios e seja feliz. Não tem por que não fazer, é o que todo mundo faz. Inclusive criam projetos auxiliares que nem são códigos.

Se quiser insistir, [tem uma solução no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14680329/221800). Não pense que é simples lidar corretamente. Não sei se terá tudo o que deseja e principalmente se compensa o esforço, especialmente quando algo sair errado.

No seu caso, me parece que os projetos são tão distintos que não valeria nem tentar colocar tudo em um repositório só.

E é claro que se quiser tratar como uma coisa só, não tem segredo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 4):

Eu realmente desconheço a configuração que possibita a inclusão de mais de um projeto no mesmo repositório, da forma que você sugeriu.

Mas, uma alternativa seria você utilizar uma função do Git `subtree` que permite a possibilidade de estruturar diferentes repositórios, de tal modo que passe a impressão que está tudo em um mesmo.

Esse recurso do git permite gerenciar multiplos repositórios de tal forma:

```
Repositorio
   |--- Reposotorio_1.0
   |    |--- index.html
   |    |--- README.md
   |    |
   |    |--- Repositorio_1.1
   |         |--- index.html
   |         |--- README.md
   |    
   |--- Reposotorio_2.0
   |    |--- index.html
   |    |--- README.md
   |  
   |--- README.md
```

Os passos em base consistem em:

1. Criar os repósitorios que serão utilizados
2. Criar os Remotes para cada um dos repositórios

   ```
   git remote add repositorio-1_0 https://github.com/usergit/Repositorio-1_0.git
   git remote add repositorio-1_0 https://github.com/usergit/Repositorio-2_0.git
   ```
3. Adicionar os "repositórios-filhos" a partir do repositório principal

   ```
   git subtree add --prefix=Repositorio-1_0/ Repositorio-1_0 master
   git subtree add --prefix=Repositorio-2_0/ Repositorio-2_0 master
   ```

**Obs**.: *Nesse modelo deverá ficar atento com o fluxo de atualização dos repositórios, podendo ser atualizado  a partir do repositório principal para os repositórios filhos*

Exemplo com 'push'

```
    git push ---> No principal 
    git subtree add --prefix=Repositorio-1_0/ Repositorio-1_0 master
    git subtree add --prefix=Repositorio-2_0/ Repositorio-2_0 master
```

Abaixo tem uma referência para um artigo que trará mais detalhes:

> Artigo de "ROBERTO ACHAR - [Multiplos repositórios](https://showmethecode.com.br/git-subtree/)"

Comment: Olá, Luiz! Consegue detalhar algumas coisas descritas no link na sua resposta? Isto é importante pois este site pode sair do ar um dia. No SO, é importante que as respostas não dependam muito de links externos para ajudarem os usuários.

Comment: Fala @Dherik, realmente faz todo sentido!

Answer (score 1):

É possível, embora seja utilizado em casos especificos e com nivel de programação avançado.

Atualmente pode se escolher duas formas.

1 - Branch (como uma versão)

2 - subtree (já mencionado nesta questão)

Que devem ser implementadas separadamente.
Ambas as formas você encontra na documentação do GitHub.

---

- Os motivos que deve ser desencorajado tais praticas

---

---

Ambas as opções são complexas e com grande probabilidade de erros...
Vou detalhar:

Em desenvolvimento e até mesmo em produção...
Acaba sendo uma confusão...
Certamente algo do branch anterior possa interferir no branch atual...

Na Organização ao longo tempo. Fica um desastre. Embora seja separado no Git por Brach, ou ramificado como subtree...

Quando você faz a implementação final.
Sem notar previamente as devidas configurações (Que podem ser milhares) os arquivos se misturam... Causando conflito de dependências.
Mesmo que seja separada por pastas, mas existem arquivos ocultos que podem não ser substituídos.

Creio que essa função não deverá ser implementada.

O melhor é um repositório único. Com suas dependências, sendo atualizadas...
Vale lembrar que as dependências são essenciais para o funcionamento do repositório.

Não complique algo que é simples.